# Second replaceALL not working

Tags: java, regex, replace

My code doesn't want to work. I would like to replace all commas but replace these commas "," and this `},{`

```
import java.io.*;

public class converter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert.txt"));
        String zeile;

        try {
            File newTextFile = new File("C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert2.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
            while ((zeile = br.readLine()) != null) {
                zeile = zeile.replaceAll("\",\"", "\uffff").replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll("\uffff", "\",\"")
                .replaceAll("\uffff", "},{")
                .replaceAll("},{", "\uffff");
                System.out.println(zeile);
                fw.write(zeile);
            }

            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
}
```

So I want to let this comma stay which stay between `},{`, but it does not work and I get an error message `"Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1 },{`"

Comment: Dunno about the 2nd replaceAll, but the 4th one isn't going to find much to chew on.

Comment: `reaplceAll` is not called so because it replaces all the occurrences; `replace` does the same. It's called so because it replaces all the string _matching the given regular expression_.

Comment: Note that you have 5 instances of `replaceAll` there.  I suspect you didn't really want a couple of them.  And you really should break the statement down into multiple statements assigning to temps -- much easier to debug that way, and no less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

The `replaceAll()` method is taking a regular expression instead of regular string. **Curly braces have special meaning in Java Regular expressions**.

You have to escape the curly braces, otherwise they will be understood as part of regex.

However the following expression will not work correctly:

```
zeile.replaceAll("\",\"",  "\uffff")
     .replaceAll(",",      "")
     .replaceAll("\uffff", "\",\"")
     .replaceAll("\uffff", "},{")
     .replaceAll("},{",    "\uffff");
```

**Because you are using multiple calls of `replaceAll()`, you are producing multiple intermediate results**, and the results depends on the previous intermediate result.

e.g. if the content of the input string will be `",",},{`, your program will:

```
1. zeile.replaceAll("\",\"",  "\uffff")    // input = \uffff,},{
2.     .replaceAll(",",       "")          // input = \uffff}{
3.     .replaceAll("\uffff",  "\",\"")     // input = ","}{
4.     .replaceAll("\uffff",  "},{")       // input = ","}{
5.     .replaceAll("\\},\\{", "\uffff");   // input = ","}{
```

Notes:

- note that line 1 and 3 are doing the reverse change, first you replace all occurences of `","` by `\uffff` and then you just replace all of them back
- line 4 will never execute as all the occurences of `\uffff` were already replaced in line 3
- line 5 will never execute either as all the occurences of `,` was already replaced in line 2

Comment: doenst work i try bye my own this way .replaceAll("\\},\\{", "\uffff"), but its still deleting

Answer (score 0):

Characters `{` and `}` have a special meaning in regular expressions (quantifier). Escape these characters using `\`.

Escape this for Java using a second `\`.

Result: `.replaceAll("\\},\\{", "\\uffff");`

**Update**

Change the order of your replacements as following:

```
       zeile = zeile.replaceAll("\",\"", "\uffff")    //backup any "," 
                    .replaceAll("\\},\\{", "\ueeee")  //backup any },{
                    .replaceAll(",", "")              //replace all commas that are still in the string
                    .replaceAll("\uffff", "\",\"")    //restore ","
                    .replaceAll("\ueeee", "},{");     //restore },{
```